# Using show with a list of lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, types

I'm having some trouble using `show` to print the rows of a matrix given by a list of lists.

I have this:

```
data Matrix = Mat Int [[Bit]] 
    deriving Eq
```

Where the argument `Int` is the order of the squared matrix and `Bit` is an Int (0 or 1). I need that my code to be able to do the following, with `Matrix` as an instance of `Show`:

```
Main> Mat 3 [[0,0,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]
[0,0,1]
[1,0,1]
[0,0,1]
```

So far I only have:

```
instance Show Matrix where
    show (Mat i (x:xs)) = (show x) ++ "\n"
```

But this obviously only returns the first list. Could you help me with this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

The simple way is to `show` all rows, and put them on their own line each:

```
instance Show Matrix where
    show (Mat _ rows) = unlines $ map show rows
```

The slight drawback of that is that it also adds a newline after the last row, to avoid that, you can use

```
instance Show Matrix where
    show (Mat _ rows) = intercalate "\n" $ map show rows
```

(needs an import of `Data.List` for `intercalate`)